# How to determine the extension's directory

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I need to get the path of the extension installed directory from JavaScript.

My goal is to write to a JSON file within the extension directory from a Firefox extension. In order to do that, I need to determine the directory in which the extension is installed within the Firefox profile.

I use this code:

```
function writeToFile()
{
    var id  = "plugin@uua";// The extension's id from install.rdf(i.e. <em:id>)
    var ext = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
                        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager)
                        .getInstallLocation(id)
                        .getItemLocation(id);
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(ext.path); 
    file.append("config.json");     
    var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]   
                             .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
    foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0); 
    var data = '[ {"id" : "2"} ]';
    foStream.write(data, data.length);
    foStream.close();
```

It throws the following error:

```
TypeError:Components.classes['@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1'] is undefined.
```

**I essentially need to get the path of the extension automatically from JavaScript.**
I double checked the ID of my extension and I also tried writing to files from other extensions with no luck.

---

Thanks very much for your replies. It didn't let me solve my problem instantly anyway but it forced me to reading Mozilla documentation. I finally got a hang of how it works. Thanks again.

**Solution to the question above:**

```
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
    AddonManager.getAddonByID("plugin_id", function(addon) {

    var uri = addon.getResourceURI("config.json");
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    var stringUri = uri.asciiSpec;
    stringUri = stringUri.replace(new RegExp(/\//g), '\\');
    stringUri = stringUri.slice(8);
    alert(stringUri);
    file.initWithPath(stringUri);
    alert(addon.hasResource("config.json"));

    var stream = FileUtils.openFileOutputStream(file,
                                                FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY 
                                                | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE 
                                                | FileUtils.MODE_TRUNCATE);
    stream.write(dataToWrite, dataToWrite.length);
    stream.close();
```

Comment: I think you'll need to be sure that your extension is unpacked in order to write files to it's install directory.

Comment: so you may want to save the file in the user's profile directory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Firefox 4 you should be using the [Add-on Manager API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager):

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getAddonByID(id, function(addon)
{
  var uri = addon.getResourceURI("config.json");
  if (uri instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL)
    writeToFile(uri.file);
});
```

Note that the new API is asynchronous, fetching the data about an extension can take time. Also, you would need to specify [`<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#unpack) in your `install.rdf`, otherwise your extension will not be unpacked upon installation (for performance reasons) and there will be no file on disk corresponding to `config.json` (it will rather be a location inside the packed XPI file). There is another issue with writing to the extension directory: all the files there will be replaced when the extension is updated. A better idea might be writing to a file in the profile directory, then you won't need to sacrifice performance.

Writing to a file can be simplified using [FileUtils.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm):

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var stream = FileOutputStream.openFileOutputStream(file, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE);
stream.write(data, data.length);
stream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 4 replaced use of nsIExtensionManager in favor of [Add-on Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager).

So you should use the [Add-on Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager) instead for FF >= 4

Answer (score 0):

You can find the user's profile directory with:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.dirsvc.get("ProfD", Ci.nsILocalFile)
```

It's probably a better idea to save your file here, but I don't know the context.